# Trying to use opencv resize with Pillow image

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I am trying to read an image from the file, and then trying to resize it using opencv library in Python 3.6.4

I am getting error in this line:
resized = cv2.resize(src = numpy.array(image), dsize = (9, 8), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
TypeError: src data type = 17 is not supported while running the code in docker, but everything seems to be working in local machine.

Following is my code:

```
pil_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(filedata))
image = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.asarray(pil_image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized = cv2.resize(src = numpy.array(image), dsize = (9, 8), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

What can be the possible issue with docker image, am i missing any dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could not be reproduced neither in Python 3 nor in Python 2.

`type = 17` means that your image is of type `CV_8SC3`, meaning that it has three channels of signed 8-bit values. This is odd, because it indicates that your conversion to grayscale didn't work out.

What you can do to debug this is to watch the shape and dtype of your arrays. For example like this:

```
im = numpy.asarray(pil_image)
print (im.shape, im.dtype)
image = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print (image.shape, image.dtype)
```

Second `print` normally would have two numbers and `uint8` as the type. If you have different output there, this might indicate the root of your problem.